# Images don't stay together when I resize website

Tags: html, css

I make a website with 3 images side by side. I actually wanted to get those 3 games centered in the middle of the website, but I don't quite get on how to get it done, so I'm okay for now.

But now when I RESIZE the website the images they change positions.

I tried to fix this without success.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(achtergrondimage.png);
  width: 100%;
}

.home2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 49.7%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.center {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 225px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.homefarcry img {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-style: solid;
}

.homefifa18 img {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-style: solid;
}

.homeoverwatch img {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="homefarcry">
    <div class="farcry5">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91j3CuFDMiL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="farcry 5" style="float: left;width: 30%; margin-right: 1%;margin-bottom: 1em" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="homefifa18">
    <div class="fifa18">
      <img src="https://resources.budgetgaming.nl/boxarts/118979_fifa18ps4kopen.jpg" alt="fifa18" style="float: left; width: 30%;  margin-right: 1%;margin-bottom: 1em" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overwatch">
    <div class="homeoverwatch">
      <div> <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTUwMFgxMTk2/z/5p8AAOSw65FXuyoV/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007" alt="OverWatch" style="float: left; width: 30%;margin-right: 1%;margin-bottom: 1em">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful code. Looks like there was just some added, because you can't create a question with only a jsfiddle link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: what code should i add here. can is there something you want or can i paste the whole code in here ? im new to stackoverflow

Comment: `.img-containter{text-align:center} .img-container img{display:inline:block}`

Comment: friendly fox if you are there here a link : 

https://jsfiddle.net/PeterLeger/4dx105fd/6/#&togetherjs=7B1V55nG38

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4dx105fd/1/#&togetherjs=7B1V55nG38

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(achtergrondimage.png);
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

This should align them to the center while making sure they never break on the next line.

I used flexbox and justify-content: center on .img-container to align them to the center and flex-wrap: nowrap so they don't break